# Chrome internal DNS cache

Tags: google-chrome, dns

I am having a problem with Chrome where Chrome tabs seem to ignore changes to Chromes internal DNS cache.

Using the Chrome DNS page (chrome://net-internals/#dns) I can see the IP for the domain changing however if I refresh a tab that points at the domain the tab does not use the new DNS value. It always use the DNS entry it first loaded with.

Disabling the Chrome cache does not fix this issue. I am waiting about 1 minutes after the change to see if the change has taken effect.3

I think this might be related to Chrome using a cached socket for the request. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: yes you need to Flush socket pools too, chrome must have kept the socket open for that domain so its using the same socket for future requests.

Comment: can this be done via code, i.e. a chrome extension?

Comment: yes i can be done, if the socket is opened from the extension itself. See the API docs https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket